# Can't download into /media/.../MyDisk (NTFS) - Permission denied

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem, disk

I'm trying to set my disk as a download folder for `qBitTorrent`. The problem is that when I'm trying to choose `/media/milano/Milano Disk` - here is my disk mounted.

But nothing is being downloaded and when I try to open the folder using qBitTorrent it says:

[image]

Which is weird because `qBitTorrent` is running under `milano` user and `Milano Disk` has these permissions:

```
milano@milano-desktop:~$ ls -la /media/milano/
total 24
drwsrwsrwx+ 3 root   root    4096 lis  7 16:19  .
drwsrwsrwx  3 root   root    4096 dub 11  2020  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 milano milano 16384 zář  7 23:57 'Milano Disk'
```

Do you have an idea where is the problem? The same problem is when I try to use a different disk to be the destination.

Comment: ... and it is formatted ext4?

Comment: @Rinzwind No, it's NTFS.

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, the Ubuntu Software -> Permissions work! Thanks